# Ordering alphabetically words and numbers in django

Tags: python, django

I have a queryset to be ordered alphabetically. I have this series of names such as:
Mission 1, Mission 2 etc.
My problem is that, once the database has more than 9 entries, the sorting works like that:
Mission 1, Mission 11, Mission 2, Mission 3 etc.
I tried a query like:

```
Mission.objects.all().order_by('name')
```

My Mission model is:

```
class Mission(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
duration_dual = models.DurationField(blank=True, null=True)
duration_solo = models.DurationField(blank=True, null=True)
training_course = models.ForeignKey(
    TrainingCourse, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
note = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
solo_flight = models.BooleanField(default=False)
created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.training_course.name + ' ' + self.name
```

but the problem is still there.
I need to have an order like --> Mission 1, Mission 2 .... Mission 9, Mission 10, Mission 11 etc.

Comment: can u show me Mission model ?

Comment: In misson model make sure your name field should be textfeild and then u can query like above

Comment: I edited my question and added mission model. What you suggested didn't work actually.

Comment: The '1' in the Mission is also a character because it is a charfield. So when you write 'Mission 1', 'Mission 2' etc. It is considered as a string so it is not possibel to arrange them the way you want with the name field as it will always start ordering alphabetically.